# Running Windows 10 Mobile Emulator in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have already installed Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 10 SDK and Emulators. However, i could not create and start emulator in my machine. There is lack of tutorial how we can create emulator and start it.

Some people say we should create this emulator by using HYPER-V. What are the steps for this process?,

What i try to do is very simple, testing my Windows 10 universal application in Windows 10 mobile phone emulator.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing?Are you getting the emulators listing in visual studio?

Comment: No i can not see any emulator in listing because as i said above i haven't crated yet. My real question is how can i create?

Comment: Are you sure you installed emulators ?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I installed emulators by using executable file downloaded

Comment: When i try to install emulators again, system gives me an error message "emulators up to date". However, what i could not understand is to create emulators, and see these emulators in Visual Studio 2015 listing. None of the comments is not about answer my problem.

Comment: Maybe...You need HyperV in place first (although I think not, the emulators should appear when you try to click the Run button). To setup HyperV, make sure you turn it on (Control Panel > "Turn Windows Features On or Off and Select Hyper-V from the list) and also, make sure you enable Virtualization from BIOS settings.

Answer (score 3):

Same here. Seems that they're only visible when you switch the platform to x86. When you select x86,  Visual Studio blinks twice and shows Windows 10 Mobile emulators in the dropdown list. Change back to ARM processor and they´re gone. If you have a real ARM device (say, a Lumia), you must switch to ARM before you debug you app. I searched a lot, but I found no info on ARM-based Windows 10 Mobile emulators.